# call a controller function from another controller

Tags: php, yii, controller

I have 2 `controllers`, let's call them c1 and c2. Now I want to call a function in c2, Let's say `actionC2`, from a function in c1.

I tried something like this:
`$c2_instance = new c2();`
`$c2_instance->actionC2();`

but it won't work. I get this error: `Missing argument 1 for CController::__construct()`.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: maybe its important to say that it falls on the first line

Comment: You are missing the argument when calling `CController`, add it when calling `CController($argument)` or remove the need for the argument.

Comment: @user488074 Though this can be a solution for the short time , it will bite back you heavily later.

Comment: You should never call an controller "method" from another controller, controllers must only have "actions" if you want to share a method use a helper

Comment: Separate the code out into it's own CAction class, can be used by both then.

Answer (score 3):

You should not call a controller from another controller . You should redirect using this

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action'));
```

And if you do not have exactly no way other that than , ***reconsider your design*** . ***Solve*** the problem , do not try to ***hide*** it. It will bite back you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As @user488074 said, your controller must have an argument that it is looking for when you create an instance of it. Go to that controller and look at what it is looking for in the contstruct function. If you don't want to pass an argument all the time for this controller then add something like this to the construct function argument

```
public function foo($argument = NULL){
}
```

so it has a default value if you don't want to pass something.

Comment: @MD.Sahib's answer is much better for the yii framework, however you may still need to look at what arguments your controller needs to instantiate itself and understand that.